# How to store an image from http server to local folder? c# (win8, app)

Tags: c#, http, directory, store

I want to store an image to a local folder, which i receive from a http-server.

The request (http://myServer:myPort/?imageID=5) delivers a "tif-image-file". If I enter this request into the Internet-Explorer, it works!

My c#-code:

```
(...)
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://myServer:myPort/?imageID=5");
StorageFile myFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(myUri);
(...)
```

But "myFile" is always null :(

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Invisibly

Answer (score 0):

OK here is my solution:

1. I created an empty file in my folder

   ```
    string myFilename = "myfile.tif";
    StorageFile myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(myFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
   ```
2. BackgroundDownloader

   ```
    try
    {
        var download = new BackgroundDownloader().CreateDownload(myUri, myFile);
        await download.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        ...
    }
   ```

The next problem is, it works only if I change the Release-Mode from "X64" to "AnyCPU" and vice versa each time. If I dont change the Release-Mode my app does nothing. No Exception, no program crash...

Is this a bug?

(sorry for my bad english...)

Answer (score -1):

The `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` method is itended to be used to load local application ressources. So it's not suited for your case. You need to create a new `Storage` file using the `CreateStreamedFileAsnyc` method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfileasync.aspx

EDIT: In your case it'll be easier to use `CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfilefromuriasync.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that works, but the next problem is, that I can´t save the StorageFile "myFile"...

    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.(...);
    string filename = "image.tif";
    
    await myFile.CopyAsync(folder, filename);

There is no Exception, the App simply stops...

Comment: did you ever happen to figure out this error? CreateStreamdFileFromUriAsync retrieves the file, but I get the exception "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)" when I try to do CopyAsync from that streamed file to the storagefile. any ideas?